# Accessing this in react, then this.props transform props in an empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I console.log(this) in a componentDidMount() and I can see everything (props.betAmounts) well formatted and with the data. However, in the same componentDidMount(), when I console.log(this.props.betAmounts) I get an empty object...

This is a codeSandBox with the explicit problem (visible in the console).

https://codesandbox.io/s/726jjqozzq

[image: Edit 726jjqozzq]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `if(this.state.betAmounts !== undefined || this.state.betAmounts !== null ) { return( <MyComponent betAmounts = {this.state.betamounts} />)}`. This solution will help you.

Comment: componentDidMount of parent is mostly called after the child componentDidMount and hence in the child componentDidMount the data isn't actually available since the parent componentDidMount sets the state

Comment: Becuase `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted

So in `index.js` you can use `componentWillMount()` instead of `componentDidMount()`

`componentWillMount()` is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before `render()`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling `setState` from within your `componentDidMount` you'll see the intermediate state, so on your first render your `betAmounts` will be the `{}` from your `App` state, therefore you'll see the empty object.

The documentation on [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) touches on this

`Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state.`

This means that since `componentDidMount` is only called once, it'll display your empty object, on the second pass (from the extra triggered render) it'll be the object you expect.

Comment: I am not so sure I understand. The problem is not in the setState, but more just in the console.log, no ? l.25.26, it changed, but I touch nothing...

Comment: @Gouigoui, I added a small explanation in my comments. also check the duplicate